# How to add column delimiter to Pandas dataframe display

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

For example, define

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(6,6)))
df
```

Which gives below display in Jupyter notebook

[image]

My question is that is it possible to add a column delimiter to the dataframe like

[image]

---

Thank you for all the answers, currently I use below custom functions

```
def css_border(x,pos):
        return ["border-left: 1px solid red" if i in pos else "border: 0px" for i, col in enumerate(x)]
def display_df_with_delimiter(df,pos):
    return df.style.apply(partial(css_border,pos=pos), axis=1)
```

and

```
display_df_with_delimiter(df,[0,1,2,5])
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This piece of code should add the desired lines to the table.

```py
from IPython.display import display, HTML

CSS = """
.rendered_html td:nth-child(even) {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
"""

HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS))
```

Note that you can change the style of those linse by simply changing the definition of `border-left` attribute, i.e `border-left: 2px solid green` to make the lines thicker and green.

Here is a snapshot demonstrating the output.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Matus Dubrava. Thank you so much for your solution. it indeed gives the exactly the same looking as my image in the post. But that image just serves as as example. How to control the delimiter position freely? And how to wrap it in a function that does not affect other dataframe display?

Answer (score 7):

Try with `pandas.style.apply(...)`:

```py
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

def css_border(x):
    return ["border-left: 1px solid red" if (i%2==0) else "border: 0px" for i, col in enumerate(x)]

html = (
    df.style.apply(css_border, axis=1).render()
)
display(HTML(html))
```

Comment: Hi, Grzegorz Skibinski. Thanks for answering. It seems that your solution is not working. It didn't output a dataframe view

Comment: It's HTML code - I'm not sure, cause I don't have jupyter at hand - but maybe try now

Comment: Yup, just checked it - this will indeed do. Now you can modify styles per columns - as per list comprehension inside ```css_border``` function.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. But with a problem what it will display all the rows

Comment: Hold on - it does display all the rows - I mean it shouldn't truncate anything there

Answer (score 3):

Usually, we do this:

```
df[[0,1,2,3]]
```

and it will print columns 0 to 3 - if you want columns 0-1 and 2-3 printed separately:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

CSS = """
.output {
    flex-direction: row;
}
"""

HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS))
```

and then call display for dataframe as:

```
display(df[[0,1]])
display(df[[2,3]])
```

Let me know if this helps!

> UPDATE: Add lines in CSS as follows:

```
CSS = """
.rendered_html td:nth-last-child(2n) {
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
"""
```

It adds red lines for every 2nd column - ofcourse you can edit the number of 'n' here as you like.

Hope this helps!

> UPDATE: UPDATE: for every n-value CSS:

```
def delimit_views(delimiters):
    output = str()
    for delim in delimiters:
       output += ".rendered_html td:nth-child("+str(delim)+") {
       border-left: 1px solid red;}"
    return output
```

And now append this CSS to the HTML for your display.

Hope it works this time!

Comment: Hi, Ramsha Siddiqui. Thank you for answering. I tried your solution, but it display two separate dataframe, which is not what I want. I want a single dataframe delimitered by visual lines

Comment: Hi! Let me edit the CSS to fix red-lines in that case.

Comment: OK, your solution is quite similar to Matus Dubrava. Thank you but as I said to Matus Dubrava. What if I want to delimiter at arbitrary position like 2,3,5，and how to restore the default dataframe rendering, so that other dataframe is not affected?

Comment: nth-child does allow you to select each child separately - so in your CSS - you'll add one border for child 2, one for 3 and one for 4 - you can also create your CSS pragmatically for every child given a list of values, by simply populating 'n'.

Comment: I tried `CSS =delimit_views([1,2,4])`, but it doesn't work

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS)), it does work. Thank you so much for explanation

Comment: yet another problem. I found that if I set CSS, it affect all the displayed dataframe in current jupyter notebook. And if I set CSS='', all the previous displayed dataframe restore to normal mode. Is it possible to keep the lines as it is after dataframe is displayed?